# Setting ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to an UNC Path

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, process.start

I have a utility that I have written in VB.net that runs as a scheduled tasks.  It internally calls another executable and it has to access a mapped drive.  Apparently windows has issues with scheduled tasks accessing mapped drives when the user is not logged on, even when the authentication credentials are supplied to the task itself. Ok, fine.

To get around this I just passed my application the UNC path.

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = 'name of executable'
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = '\\unc path\'
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
process.StartInfo.Arguments = 'arguments to executable'
process.Start()
```

This is the same implementation I used with the mapped drive, however using the UNC path, the process is not behaving as if the UNC path is the working directory.

Are there any known issues setting ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to an UNC path?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem with mapped drives when users aren't logged in is that they don't exist. Drives are only mapped and available to the currently logged in user. If no one is logged in, no drives are mapped.

As a workaround you can run through CMD, call PUSHD which will map your UNC to a drive behind the scenes and then execute your code. I've copied the tree.com file from my system32 and placed it on my file server as "tree4.com" and this code works as expected (I'm also redirecting standard output so I can see the results of the call but that's not necessary)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using P As New Process()
        'Launch a standard hidden command window
        P.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

        'Needed to redirect standard error/output/input
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        'Add handler for when data is received
        AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf SDR

        'Start the process
        P.Start()

        'Begin async data reading
        P.BeginOutputReadLine()

        '"Map" our drive
        P.StandardInput.WriteLine("pushd \\file-server\File-Server")

        'Call our command, you could pass args here if you wanted
        P.StandardInput.WriteLine("tree2.com  c:\3ea7025b247d0dfb7731a50bf2632f")

        'Once our command is done CMD.EXE will still be sitting around so manually exit
        P.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")
        P.WaitForExit()
    End Using

    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub SDR(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Data)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem and the accepted solution is a little complicated for me. What I did was to take the UNC path and copy the contents of it to `[Path.GetTempDir()]\[Guid.NewGuid().ToString()]` and then use that as my Working Directory for the `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`. Wrap this functionality in a class called "Environment" which will implement IDisposable and in the dispose clean up the temp directory you created. Something like this (ignore the settings references):

```
 using (var env = new ProcessEnvironment(settings))
                {
                    filePath = Path.Combine(env.WorkingDirectory, settings.ApplicationEXE);
                    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = filePath,
                        WorkingDirectory = env.WorkingDirectory,
                        Arguments = (args != null && args.Length > 0 ? String.Join(" ", args) : null)
                    };

                    var proc = Process.Start(psi);

                    if (env.ExecutingFromTempDir || settings.WaitForExit)
                        proc.WaitForExit();
                }
```

And ProcessEnvironment looks like:

```
 class ProcessEnvironment : IDisposable
    {
        private Settings itsSettings;
        private string itsTempDestDirectory;
        public string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }
        public bool ExecutingFromTempDir { get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(itsTempDestDirectory); } }

        public ProcessEnvironment(Settings settings)
        {
            this.itsSettings = settings;

            WorkingDirectory = GetWorkingDirectory();
        }

        private string GetWorkingDirectory()
        {
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(itsSettings.StartupFolder);

            if (!IsUncDrive(dirInfo))
                return itsSettings.StartupFolder;

            return CreateWorkingDirectory(dirInfo);
        }

        private string CreateWorkingDirectory(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
        {
            var srcPath = dirInfo.FullName;
            itsTempDestDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            Directory.CreateDirectory(itsTempDestDirectory);

            //Now Create all of the directories
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(srcPath, itsTempDestDirectory));

            //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(srcPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(srcPath, itsTempDestDirectory), true);

            return itsTempDestDirectory;
        }

        private bool IsUncDrive(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
        {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(dirInfo.FullName, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return uri.IsUnc;
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ExecutingFromTempDir)
                    Directory.Delete(itsTempDestDirectory, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  //do nothing - if we can't delete then we can't do it
                Console.WriteLine("Failed in Dispose: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```